# Invalid or corrupt jarfile error when trying to execute jhindexer

Tags: java, windows, jar

I'm trying to create the database for my Java project using jhindexer. As far as i know, the process that i have to follow to achieve this is:

- Go to my help folder
- Run jhindexer with the folder where my html are stored (in my case it's called sources)
- This will generate the JavaHealpSearch folder with some file inside
- I can run jhsearch with the JavaSearchHelp folder to test everything is fine

But when I execute the jhindexer I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\novayhulk14
```

No JavaHelpSearch folder is generated. I'm using JavaHelp 2.0_05, which is the version I have from another project. I've tried to find a more recent version but I couldn't.

Comment: What is the full jhindexer command you are running?

Comment: @VGR in the help folder: path-to-jhindexer sources

Comment: Does `jhindexer -verbose sources` provide any useful information?

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: Is any additional information printed?

Comment: No, It's exactly the same error message I've posted